# Combine two counting queries into one Boolean query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I can't think of a good way to write this as a single query.

```
int count1 = query1.Count();
int count2 = query2.Count();

return count1 > count2;
```

Please note that I'm interested in ways to write a **single** query that returns a Boolean value and gets evaluated once on the server.

Please note that I'm interested in ways to write this with LINQ, not with SQL.

Comment: Might be more help if you tell us what the queries are.

Comment: They could be anything. Assume query1 is db.Customers and query2 is db.Products.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
return query1.Count() > query2.Count();
```

It's not worth trying to run two unrelated queries in the same server call, but here it is:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products) 
        > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) 
            THEN CAST(1 as bit) 
            ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
```

However, I seriously doubt you can get LINQ to create this kind of query.  You would have to call a stored procedure instead.

Comment: No, this compares the results of issuing two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
var result= query1.Count() > query2.Count();

return result; // result is of type bool
```

EDIT:

If you really want to execute it as one query on the server, you could use DataContext.ExecuteQuery to execute a dynamic query.

Comment: No, this compares the results of issuing two separate queries.